# Spring testing plugin without context

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have a plugin for my application which has only one class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Supplier messageSupplier(){
        return () -> "plugin";
    }
}
```

I use it in other application but I want to test this class. I want to test it, but I don't know what is context of this application.

Comment: Could you please provide more explanations: what kind of tests do you want to do (unit, integration and so on), what exactly do you expect to be tested?

Comment: I want to add some services and repositories and I would like to write integration tests.